# Installing pycurl on mac

Tags: python, libcurl, pycurl

I am very new to python and need help installing the pycurl library on my machine.  I am running python 2.7 at the moment.  A brief tutorial would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Use one of the two methods

Method 1: 
sudo easy_install pycurl

Method 2: 
pip install pycurl

Answer (score 3):

Try specify the `ARCHFLAGS` env var:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install pycurl==7.19.5.1
```