# Error when Installing Pycurl on OS X

Tags: python, macos, gcc, osx-mavericks, pycurl

I am trying to install pycurl on OS X Mavericks. I have downloaded and installed the Xcode dev tools to have some compiler. I went into the Xcode preferences and made sure that I have downloaded all the compliers I would need but still getting this error

When I try to install pycurl I get the following errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
local-mbp:~ $ sudo easy_install pycurl
Password:
Searching for pycurl
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/
Best match: pycurl 7.19.3.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycurl/pycurl-7.19.3.1.tar.gz#md5=6df8fa7fe8b680d93248da1f8d4fcd12
Processing pycurl-7.19.3.1.tar.gz
Running pycurl-7.19.3.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-jKMmtE/pycurl-7.19.3.1/egg-dist-tmp-9z89Ns
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.30.0)
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
local-mbp:~ $ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
local-mbp:~$ which cc
/usr/bin/cc
local-mbp:~$
```

Comment: Looks like you are not the only one having problems and they are not related to python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-mavericks

Comment: The general (easiest) solution to all such problems is: Install Clang, Python and all related tools via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). The versions shipping with OS X are complicated, don’t rely on them. By exclusively relying on Homebrew you make your life vastly easier.

Comment: Ya tried to do homebrew on clang got the following error:

local-mbp:~$ brew install clang
Error: No available formula for clang
Searching taps...
local-mbp:~$

used sudo easy_install to install clang and that was successful. But still not able install pycurl

Comment: You shouldn't install `clang` with `easy_install`!!! That doesn't install `clang`, it installs Python bindings for `clang`.

Comment: Also, you already have `clang`, as evident in your pasted output above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing pycurl on mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521587/installing-pycurl-on-mac)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
brew install python
```

Double check you are using brewed Python:

```
which python
```

(Should return something like `/usr/local/bin/python`)

Install `pycurl` with `pip`.

```
pip install pycurl
```

I just tested this on Mavericks.

Comment: Hi Daviewales.,

I tried what you have suggested. Python installed but the last step said that it wasnt able to link python to /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: Ran brew link python but said: 
Warning: Could not link python. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link python'

Used brew link python and got an error:
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/pip2.7
Target /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and overwrite all other conflicting files, do:
  brew link --overwrite formula_name

Comment: Tried to run pip install pycurl but getting the same error

Comment: I dont know if would disrupt any of my system python if I try to overwrite the python that is already there

Comment: You won't disrupt system Python. System Python doesn't live in `/usr/local`. It will be another Python that you've installed previously. (You should be able to delete it without issues.)

Answer (score 3):

Try specify the `ARCHFLAGS` env var:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install pycurl
```