# Installing pycurl for Python 2.6 on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, python-2.6, pycurl

I have a Mac OS (El Capitan 10.11.3) and I'm trying to install pycurl library for Python 2.6.9. Unfortunately, when I try:

```
 easy_install pycurl
```

I have:

```
 Searching for pycurl
 Best match: pycurl 7.19.5.3
 Processing pycurl-7.19.5.3-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg
 pycurl 7.19.5.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
```

But it is for Python 2.7 - not 2.6.

Checking current Python version in bash:

```
 python -V 
 Python 2.6.9
```

I also tried to install it manually (download .tar and install)

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Output:

```
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.43.0)
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running install_lib
running install_data
creating /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share
error: could not create '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share': Operation not permitted
```

The same for:

```
make PYTHON=python2.6
```

Do you have any idea how to make it to install pycurl for Python 2.6?

Comment: What is the problem? It is already installed. **pycurl 7.19.5.3 is already the active version**

Comment: The problem that it is for Python 2.7, not 2.6. Python 2.6 still doesn't see pycurl

Comment: How do you know that? Your `python -V` shows version 2.6

Comment: Because I'm trying to import pycurl in the Python interpreter. It says: ImportError: No module named pycurl. Moreover "pycurl-7.19.5.3-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg" is definitely for 2.7, as you can see

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing pycurl on mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521587/installing-pycurl-on-mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sudo python2.6 -m easy_install pycurl
```

Outputs

```
Installed /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pycurl-7.43.0-py2.6-macosx-10.11-intel.egg
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that, if possible, you avoid installing packages directly into your system. Try to use them based on your projects, using tools such as [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). This way it avoids conflicts, and you can also choose specific versions if needed.